# creating a webserver (httpd) using vsftpd in centos

Tags: centos, httpd

I want to create a webserver, to host websites, i have configured vsftpd, i have created user with default directory /home/sam , i am able to access the files using filezilla. but if i am creating a directory /var/www/liz i am not able to upload are download in filezilla. if i put selinux is permissive mode i am able to access, but i want to access the files keeping selinux in enforcing mode. and i want the folder /var/www/liz to be the default folder for apache were user and upload files so that it can be hosted directly from the folder /var/www/liz. thanks in advance

Comment: Which user did you use to create `/var/www/liz`? Is there a particular reason you want selinux enabled?

Comment: for user liz , i thought by keeping selinux enabled it will be secure

Comment: Have you done any research on configuring vsftpd or apache? Or SELinux?

Comment: i am a fresher i tried setting labels like chcon -t public_content_rw_t but didnt work